# How to add required rule to antd input with initial value as undefined?

Tags: forms, reactjs, validation, antd

I have created a `form` as a component which is used in `create` and `update` components. so when create uses this form component I don't pass any props as initial values for the form fields.
But inside update I pass initials after they have been fetched from server.

```js
<FormItem {...formItemLayout} >
   {getFieldDecorator('username', { initialValue: user.username || null }, {
       rules: [{ required: true, message: "نام کاربری را وارد کنید." }]
   })(
     <Input
      type="text"
      placeholder="نام کاربری"/>
   )}
</FormItem>
```

I expect the `username` field to be validated like before I didn't add `initialValue`.

But I doesn't get any error after submit as before adding `initialValue` if the `username` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you didn't put the initialValue on the right place , try this (works for me ) :

```
<FormItem {...formItemLayout} >
  {getFieldDecorator('username',  {
   initialValue: user.username || null,
   rules: [{ required: true, message: "نام کاربری را وارد کنید." }]
  })(
  <Input
   type="text"
   placeholder="نام کاربری"/>
 )}
</FormItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of initialValue, you can use setFieldsValue method and set the initial values for your labels like this:

```
setInitialValues = () => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    form.setFieldsValue({
        username: user.username
    });
};
```

Your form should remain the same, just get rid of initialValue:

```
<FormItem {...formItemLayout} >
{getFieldDecorator('username', {
   rules: [{ required: true, message: "نام کاربری را وارد کنید." }]
})(<Input
  type="text"
  placeholder="نام کاربری"/>
)}
</FormItem>
```

And don't forget to call the function setInitialValues in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setInitialValues();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding **required** attribute on your input tag?
Like this:

```
<Input
  type="text"
  placeholder="نام کاربری" 
  required/>
```

And eventually, to set an error message, you would need to use `validationErrors` attribute

The end result would look like this:

```
<Input
  type="text"
  placeholder="نام کاربری" 
  required
  validationErrors={{
      isDefaultRequiredValue: 'Field is required'
  }}/>
```